# C# Timer Skips Code

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, event-handling

I tell the Timer to start in the constructor. It starts, but when it reaches its Timer.Elapsed event it only runs the first if statement in the method. I've checked to see if `isWatching` is true, and it is, but it still skips it entirely. It doesn't even reach the `if(isWatching)` line.

Code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   
    public SessionManager SM { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        SM = new SessionManager();
        SM.NewDayEvent += SplitSession;
        ///code
    }
}
```

**SessionManager.cs** (Some variables have been omitted from this post):

```
public class SessionManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public delegate void NewDayEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs ea);
    public event NewDayEventHandler NewDayEvent;

    private bool _isWatching;
    private Timer _timer;
    private bool isWatching
    {
        get
        {
            return _isWatching;
        }
        set
        {
            _isWatching = value;
            if (!_isWatching)
            {
                _clockWatch.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                _clockWatch.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    public SessionManager()
    {
        _clockWatch = new Stopwatch();
        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += timerElapsed;//focus on this here

        _isWatching = false;
        current_time = new DateTime();
        CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (CurrentTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Parse("9:32 AM") && NewDayEvent != null)
        {
            NewDayEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        if (isWatching)
        {
            if (CurrentSession != null)
            {
                //update the timespent variable of the current timeEntry
                if (CurrentSession.currentTimeEntry != null)
                {
                    CurrentSession.currentTimeEntry.TimeSpent = _clockWatch.Elapsed;
                    calculateTotalTime();

                    CalculateFilteredTimeSpent();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running in Debug, by the way.

Comment: How about CurrentSession  value ? Is it null or not ?

Comment: @Shyju: I've checked to see if isWatching is true, and it is, but it still skips it entirely. It doesn't even reach the if(isWatching) line. If it doesn't reach that line, why would it go deeper?

Comment: Have you looked into the precision of [`TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? The chances of a match are slim.

Comment: @HABO; That may be true, but that's not the problem. My problem is, regardless of whether or not the first if statement is true, the second if statement, <code>if(isWatching)</code>, is not even reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the correct format while calling [`TimeSpan.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx). The right way to do what you are trying to is:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("9:32")
```

Your current code snippet throws a `System.FormatException`:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

However for what you are trying to achieve, trigger an action once every day at a particular time, the above method might not be the best since the chances of it succeeding are very less. The timer will run every 1000 ms and then return the current time of day which has milliseconds included. So the timer elapsed event could be called at 9:32.0001 and might never pass the condition. A better alternative is probably:

```
if (CurrentTime.TimeOfDay >= TimeSpan.Parse("9:32") && NewDayEvent != null)
```

This will trigger more than once after that time has elapsed, so you could add a flag which keeps track of what day the last event was processed.

Alternatively you could also look at ScheduleAction in .NET 4.5 or some of the solutions [here](http://if%20(CurrentTime.TimeOfDay%20%3E=%20TimeSpan.Parse(%229:32%22)%20&&%20NewDayEvent%20!=%20null)).

Comment: But I need the AM/PM part of the TimeSpan the most. Is there a way I can still have that? Also why didn't the error get thrown when I was running the code? It never said anything to me.

Comment: @SageKelly The hours in a `TimeSpan` run from 0 to 23, hence `9` is _ante meridiem_.

Comment: Check out the link above. The argument accepts time in a 24-hour format. If you were to input 9:32 PM you can simply type 21:32. For AM it is straightforward. 
The error didn't get thrown because the exception occurs on the timer _elapsed thread which is separate from your main thread. Try performing the same operation in your MainWindow.cs file and you'd see the exception.